# How to move DRM protected WMV files to a new computer?

Tags: windows-xp, video, drm

I've got some media files in WMV format that I purchased several years ago, and the vendor has since gone out of business.  The files are on an old desktop PC running Windows XP, and I'd like to move them to my new Windows 8 system.  Is there a way to retrieve the keys for these files and transfer them to the new computer?  (I'm not sure if that's even how the DRM works, just guessing that there was some kind of key generated when I originally purchased them.)  Is it even possible to move DRM-protected files between systems, or are they somehow tied to the original PC where they were purchased?

More details:

I've tried searching for the company online, and they're nowhere to be found.  I purchased this content years ago, and figured that somehow the license was tied to the physical hardware, but wasn't sure if I could still somehow transfer whatever rights are necessary to play the files.  When I try to open the .wmv files in Windows Media Player on the new system, it says:

> You do not have the rights to play this file.  Go to the content
>   provider's Web site to find out how to obtain the necessary play
>   rights. Address:  http://license.drmnetworks.com/v9.aspx

However, that link is broken, the page says "Invalid challenge string".  When I close the initial error dialog, a second one is displayed:

> Windows Media Player cannot play, burn, or sync the file because the
>   media usage rights are missing.  If you obtained the file from an
>   online store, sign in to the store, and then try again.

And no, I'm not trying to circumvent the DRM, just move the license that I paid for to my new computer.

Comment: What happened when you tried to just copy them over?

Comment: What was the original vendor's name? Have you tried googling them and seeing if they have any sort of license you can install to unlock the stuff they sold you? Did the vendor get bought by any successor company that you can contact to ask this question? The answer will depend on how restrictive the DRM system was, and whether you're looking to *legally* copy them or to somehow circumvent the DRM (which can be a violation of the law at least in the United States). Worst case, it's tied to the unique CPU by the TPM chip and you're out of luck. Best case you can just copy them over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing other posts here on DRM issues, I found a paid utility ($35 US) *Aimersoft DRM Media Converter* that can read the licensed files and convert them to various formats, removing the DRM in the process:

http://www.aimersoft.com/drm-media-converter.html

This appears to be the solution for me, I'm trying it now on my old XP system.

Comment: Aimersoft's program worked as advertised!  It converted the DRM files to .wmv format without protection.  It was well worth the $35!